# The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a beginner in JAVA and programming in general, so please be patient as I may not use the correct  terms to correctly describe my doubts. I'll do my best, nevertheless.
So, I have this ArrayList that I'm going to use regular expressions on, to split it on the commas.
I really needed some help solving this problem, even if I have to change the way that I do the process. It's not important that it stays this way, it's the final result that matters the most to me.
Thank you.

```
  String temp; 
    String temp2;
    ArrayList <String> tempsplit = new ArrayList<String> (); 
    ArrayList <String> dominios = new ArrayList<String> (); {

    for (int h = 0; h < 191; h++){
        temp = features.get(h);
        **temp2.add(temp.split(","));
        tempsplit.add(temp.split(","));** 
        //in these last couple lines I get the error "The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (String[])" 
        for(int oi = 0; oi < tempsplit.size(); oi++){
            for (int t = 0; t < dominios.size() ; t++){
                int conf = 0;
                if (tempsplit.get(oi) == dominios.get(t)){
                    conf = 0;           
                    }
                else{ conf = 1;
        }
                if (conf == 1){
                    dominios.add (tempsplit.get(oi));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well what do you *expect* it to do? If you want it to add all the values within the array, you probably want `addAll` using `Arrays.asList` to wrap the array...

Answer (score 3):

```
Collections.addAll(temp2, temp.split(","));
```

This uses the help class Collections to add a `String[]` by item.

Answer (score 3):

`temp.split(",")` returns a `String[]`.

`List<String>.add` takes a `String` as a parameter, not an array of strings.

Yet you can use [`Collections.addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)), that takes an array as second argument:

```
Collections.addAll(temp2, temp.split(","));
```

You can alternatively use the `addAll(Collection<String> c)` method from the `temp` `ArrayList<String>` but then you have to convert the array to a `Collection`:

```
temp2.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code with the problem is essentially:

```
ArrayList <String> tempsplit = new ArrayList<String>();   
tempsplit.add(temp.split(",")); // compile error
```

The problem is that `split()` returns a `String[]`, but the list will only accept a `String`.

To fix, convert the array to a List and pass it to `addAll()`:

```
tempsplit.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp.split(",")));
```

or use the utility `addAll()` method:

```
Collections.addAll(tempsplit, temp.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Arraylist is of type `String` not `String[]` and you are passing string array in `add()` because `string.split()` will give you array.Instead you can do

```
for(String a:temp.split(",")){
 tempsplit.add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The method add(String) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

This means that you have an `ArrayList<String>`, and you are trying to call the `add` method with an **array** of strings (`String[]`) instead of with a single `String`. The method needs a single `String`, not an array.